# Deselect a selected row in ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

How do I deselect a row that I have just selected using the same button that I have used to select and highlight the row from an ng-repeat list? What different options are there, does anyone have any examples or links as I can't find any?

EDIT:-
Please see Plunker using link
https://plnkr.co/edit/LYrmpLUwGaWx8wLeCOoT

code is here:-

**html**

```
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
<script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
<script data-require="angular.js@1.4.x"    src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.12/angular.js" data-semver="1.4.9"></script>
<script src="app.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
<div ng-repeat="item in items" ng-class="{sel: item.Item == selected}">
  <label>Item No. {{item.Item}}</lablel> |
  <label>{{item.Description}}</label> |
  <button ng-click="onClick(item.Item);" class="btn btn-primary">
    {{item.Item == selected ? 'Hide' : 'Show'}}
  </button>
  </div>
  <br />
  <br />
  <div ng-switch="moduleState">
            <div ng-switch-when="details">
              These are your details:-
              Item {{selected}} is selected
              </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**app.js**

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
$scope.items = [
    {
        Item: 1,
        Description: 'This is item 1'
    },
    {
        Item: 2,
        Description: 'This is item 2'
    },
    {
        Item: 3,
        Description: 'This is item 3'
    }
];

$scope.onClick = function (item) {
  $scope.selected = item;
  $scope.moduleState = 'details';
 };
});
```

Once one of the buttons is selected how do I deselect it again?

Comment: What do you mean by "select a row?" Please share a fiddle, or at least your  html.

Comment: @Kraken Just updated question

Comment: And it's still very unclear. We have no idea ow the first snippet is linked to the second one. One uses toggle and a mysteerious show() function. The other uses moduleState. Post a complete, minimal example reproducing the problem.

Comment: @JBNizet I have updated the question based on your feedback, can you help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$scope.onClick = function(item) {
  if ($scope.selected === item) {
    $scope.selected = null;
  }
  else {
    $scope.selected = item;
  }
};
```

And in the view:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items" ng-class="{sel: item.Item == selected}">
  <label>Item No. {{item.Item}}</lablel> |
  <label>{{item.Description}}</label> |
  <button ng-click="onClick(item.Item);" class="btn btn-primary">
    {{item.Item == selected ? 'Hide' : 'Show'}}
  </button>
</div>

<br />
<br />

<div ng-if="selected">
  These are your details:-
  Item {{ selected }} is selected
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Check the plunkr below:

https://plnkr.co/edit/u7I9nIRZgOMB7vqBr92n?p=preview

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.items = [
        {
            Item: 1,
            isVisible: false,
            Description: 'This is item 1'
        },
        {
            Item: 2,
            isVisible: false,
            Description: 'This is item 2'
        },
        {
            Item: 3,
            isVisible: false,
            Description: 'This is item 3'
        }
    ];
    
    $scope.onClick = function (item) {
      if(!item.isVisible) {
        item.isVisible = !item.isVisible;
        $scope.selected = item.Item;
        $scope.moduleState = 'details';
      } else {
        item.isVisible = !item.isVisible;
        $scope.selected = $scope.moduleState = "";
      }
    };
});
```

```html
<button ng-click="onClick(item);" class="btn btn-primary">
        {{item.Item == selected ? 'Hide' : 'Show'}}
      </button>
```

Basically what i did is:

1. Added a flag "isVisible" for each row
2. Toggled the flag when its set to visible
3. on second click, if its visible, hide it.